# Python Import Error: cannot import name 'literal_eval'

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I'm getting the following error while running the python program. I'm using python 3.4 and I have installed Ferenda-0.1.7-py3.4 And the error is:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\ferenda-0.1.7-py3.4.egg\ferenda\util.py", line 20, in module
  from ast import literal_eval
ImportError: cannot import name 'literal_eval'
```

Appreciate you help on this. Thank you.

When I tried running in the command prompt. I can see no errors. Attached is the picture

[image: In Command Prompt]

Comment: Try typing `from ast import literal_eval` in your shell and see what happens.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. I tried in the command prompt and I can see no error. Nothing prints in the console too.

Comment: can you please show the full traceback, starting with `Traceback (most recent call last):`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have named your script `ast.py` (or you have another script in the same directory named `ast.py`) and this script does not contain a `literal_eval`.

Comment: print `ast.__file__` to see where it is.

Comment: Hi Kindall, Thank you for the answer. There is another script in the same directory named ast.py. I deleted it and it is working fine. Thanks